# Check login on User with multiple property in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm building a multi-tenant application in Symfony2.  For the secure "admin" area I have a custom entity provider (see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)

However, it seems that Symfony2 only supports checking the entity on a single property.

```
my_entity_provider:
            entity:
                class:              SecurityBundle:User
                property:           email
```

However, in my app a single User can have multiple accounts with the same email address. What I need is to also check for a tenant ID property when logging in.

```
my_entity_provider:
            entity:
                class:              SecurityBundle:User
                property:           email, tenantID
```

I'm not sure how to accomplish this in Symfony2.  I've been able to override the loadUsername method when creating a new User, but this isn't used by the login_check in Symfony2 security (and it is really ugly).

```
 public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        /* we create a concatenated string in the  User entity to pass both
        the email and tenantId values as the "username" */
        $user_parts = explode("|", $username); 

        $q = $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->where('u.tenantId = :tenantid AND u.email = :email')
            ->setParameter('tenantID', $user_parts[1])
            ->setParameter('email', $user_parts[0])
            ->getQuery();

        try { 
            $user = $q->getSingleResult();

        } catch (NoResultException $e) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Unable to find an active User object identified by "%s".', $username), null, 0, $e);
        }

        return $user;
    }
```

Any guidance on implementing a custom security provider with multiple properties?  Thanks!

Comment: Entity provider looking for a user in a database on some unique property. The user enters the username (or email) and thus defines itself. That in your case the user enters at login?

Comment: Hi forgottenbas, thanks for your comment.  I need to lookup the user based on email AND a tenantID property.

Comment: Ok, but that your user input in login form?

Comment: I have an event listener that determines the value of the tenantID, based on the url subdomain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say you use a custom authentication provider, but I don't see where.
I think you use the **default** entity provider, which indeed, uses the associated entity **Repositiory**.

If you defined a `property` in configuration, it will use the repository ``findOneBy` method.

Otherwise, if you defined a custom `repositoryClass`, and this custom respository implements UserPrviderInterface, symfony [will call `loadUserByUsername`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/Security/User/EntityUserProvider.php#L54-L61)

So, for you example to call you loadUserByUsername method, just remove `property: email` from your security.yml

Otherwise, there are many cleaner solutions that come to my mind, but the best to my mind is to

- [create your own user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/security/custom_provider.html#modify-security-yml)

It's a simple process:

- create a class that implements UserProviderInterface
- create a service for that class (f.e with id: `app.security.user.provider`)
- configure security.yml to use this service

  1. the class: (pseudo code, don't forget to add use statements, ...)

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
public function __construct(ManagerRegistry $doctrine, $tenantIdProvider)
{
     $this->doctrine = $doctrine;
     $this->tenantIdProvider = $tenantIdProvider;
}

public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{
    $this->doctrine->getRepository('App\Entity\User')->findOneBy([
        'email' => $username,
        'tenant' => $this->tenantIdProvider->getId(), // HERE $tenantIdProvider can be your listener for example.
    ]);
}

// more methods maybe?
}
```

2. the service (services.yml, app/config/config.yml, ... where you want)

services:

```
app.security.user.provider:
    class: UserProvider
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine'
        - '@app.tenant_id.provider' #maybe?
```

3. the security config

security:

```
providers:
    user:
        id: app.security.user.provider
```

Comment: Works like a charm! For the "more methods maybe" part: You should implement, `refreshUser` and `supportsClass` methods as well, wrt UserProviderInterface as of Symfony 3.1. For the implementation of those methods, you can consult on the [How to create a custom user provider](http://symfony.com/doc/current/security/custom_provider.html) section of official Symfony documentation.

Answer (score 2):

I think overriding loadUserByUsername in your UserRepository, like you do, is the good thing to do in your case.

Maybe your problem is in the configuration :

Using the attribute "property", symfony doesn't use your own loadUserByUsername

So, simply remove the "property" line, and i hope all works :

```
my_entity_provider:
    entity:
        class: SecurityBundle:User
```

Comment: This should work, but how do I pass the tenant ID to loadUserByUsername?  I can't access the container because it isn't in a controller, it is in the User Repository.  Thanks!

Comment: Your UserProvider should extend EntityRepository (like [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html)). Then, in your loadUserByUsername, you have access to the entityManager by $this->getEntityManager().

Answer (score 1):

You've seen custom Authentication I assume? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/custom_authentication_provider.html#the-listener

Ignoring that this is for WSSE, this would allow you to create your own custom handle working with the tenant id and email address manually authenticating